# Styling individual Markdown cells in ipython notebooks

Tags: css, markdown, jupyter-notebook

How can you fix the size of a cell that contains Markdown? I tried the following with ipython 2.3:

```
<div style="max-height: 500px; overflow: auto;">

[Markdown]

</div>
```

Both style directives are ignored and the Markdown is interpreted as text. I know that the div tag is being read because I can see its effects when I add `background: yellow;` to the mix. So why are the other two directives ignored -- how can I style Markdown cells?

Comment: For me these work fine! However, You won't see any changes with your minimal example. Try something like `style="height:500px"` or increase your markdown content to span more than 500px.

Comment: @Jakob: I used a big fat Markdown table, for which the "[Markdown]" above is merely a placeholder. It did NOT render properly.

Comment: There seems to be a funny issue with tables in div containers. Can you try adding an arbitrary character right after the closing div? Btw. does the styling really don't work or is just the table not rendering?

Comment: They both failed; styling and rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be (at least) an issue with tables in div containers. This however is not attributed to IPython but rather to marked (the applied markdown engine).

I'm not perfectly sure if this is really your problem but if I create a markdown cell with the following content

```
<div style="max-height: 50px; overflow: auto;">
| 13ddsf | ree |
|------|-----|
| 33   | 45  |
</div>
```

I would expext to see a table, cropped at the bottom with a scrollbar at the side. However, I just get something like
[image]

So I don't see the table and I don't see any styling. Actually, the styling is simply not visible because the `max-height` keyword has no effect here. If I change the style to `"height: 50px;"` I immediately see the styling (note the increased height):
[image]

Now, the strange thing is actually the rendering problem of the table. Without the additional `div` container the table renders just fine, so the problem is somehow related to this container. After playing around I discovered that - for what reason ever - it is necessary to add some white space around the table. So if I change the markdown slightly like:

```
<div style="max-height: 50px; overflow: auto;">

| 13ddsf | ree |
|------|-----|
| 33   | 45  |
</div >
```

it renders as:
[image]
Note that there is a blank line before the table **and** a white space character after the final div! Actually, it works as well if the white space character after the div is skipped and some text is added outside the final div.
This way everything works as expected, ie. rendering and styling. Nevertheless, I'll write a bug report to marked, as this is IMHO not really obvious.

#### Update:

This seem to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/chjj/marked/issues/236), which explains why the initial code is not working. Actually block-level markdown is not allowed inside block-level inline html. Moreover marked needs 2 line feeds after the block to correctly find it. By preventing marked to identify the block-level
html (e.g. by adding the white space) it is possible to get the desired result, although in a somehow hackish way.
Note, that it is likely that this hack won't work forever, as the block level parsing might be modified.

Btw. I use the current IPython master (commit_hash: '13e42d6'), ubuntu and firefox 33.

Comment: Oh, wow! I'd discovered the important of the space after the opening div tag but not the space _inside_ the closing div tag. Should we file a bug report?

Comment: Well it's no real bug. It is simply not supported to write markdown blocks in html blocks, and here we introduce a parsing error to overcome this limitation. You can actually remove the closing div completely and it still works.